# Create an object containing an array of different objects that can grow dynamically in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, object, powershell-2.0

I want to create an object in PowerShell with one of its private members being a list or array of different objects. There are two important features for this request.

1. The private member list or array must be able to **grow dynamically** (how would this work syntactically?)
2. The solution must be **backwards compatible with PowerShell 2.0**. This means I can't create a custom class using the "class" keyword.

Is there a way this can be done in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for something like this (works in v2 ):

```
$x = New-Object psobject
$arr = new-object system.collections.arraylist
$arr.add("test")
$arr.add("test3")
$arr.add(@{"test4"="another1"})
$x | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name arr -Value $arr
$x.arr.add("test5")
write-output $x.arr
```

by default arrays are polymorphic in powershell , so you can store any type in the array and pass it into the object

private members are not possible in v2 ([PowerShell - how to add private members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543834/powershell-how-to-add-private-members))

Comment: This may be the solution. I can't tell if the solution worked though because Write-Output has a hard time writing it all. Do you know how I can properly write the output (nicely) so that I would see the parent object with its array of smaller objects?

Comment: @wOxxOm I have updated the answer,thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning if you can add a sample output formatting ,then i can check for that

Answer (score 0):

just do it:

```
#declaration array and variables differents types
$array=@()
$varstring='i am as tring'
$varint=0
$varobject=New-Object -TypeName "pscustomobject" @{val1="12"; val2="test"}

#add elements into array
$array+=$varstring
$array+=$varint
$array+=$varobject

#print array
$array
```